# Validate Form without refreshing "radiobutton doesn't work"

Tags: jquery, validation

I need help i found this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/)  for validating form without refreshing but the problem is i think this is for just text fields :) but i'm using 4 different radiobuttons i really need this script to work with these radiobutton !

here is the javascript file :) !

```
runOnLoad(function(){
  $("input#name").select().focus();         
});

$(function() {        
    $('.error').hide();        
    $(".button").click(function() {  

        // validate and process form here  
        $('.error').hide(); 
        var name = $("input#name").val();  

        if (name == "") {  
            $("label#name_error").show();  
            $("input#name").focus();  
            return false;  
        }  

        var email = $("input#email").val();  
        if (email == "") {  
            $("label#email_error").show();  
            $("input#email").focus();  
            return false;  
        }  

        var mobile = $("input#mobile").val();  
        if (mobile == "") {  
            $("label#mobile_error").show();  
            $("input#mobile").focus();  
            return false;  
        }  

        var college = $("input#college").val();  
        if (college == "") {  
            $("label#college_error").show();  
            $("input#college").focus();  
            return false;  
        }  

        var university = $("input#university").val();  
        if (university == "") {  
          $("label#university_error").show();  
          $("input#university").focus();  
          return false;  
        }  

        var level = $("input#level").val();  
        if (level == "") {  
          $("label#level_error").show();  
          $("input#level").focus();  
          return false;  
        }  

        var first_preference = $("input#first_preference").val();  
            if (first_preference == "") {  
          $("label#first_preference_error").show();  
          $("input#first_preference").focus();  
          return false;  
        }  

        var second_preference = $("input#second_preference").val();  
        if (second_preference == "") {  
          $("label#second_preference_error").show();  
          $("input#second_preference").focus();  
          return false;  
        }  

        var third_preference = $("input#third_preference").val();  
        if (third_preference == "") {  
          $("label#third_preference_error").show();  
          $("input#third_preference").focus();  
          return false;  
        }  

        var heard = $("input#heard").val();  
        if (heard == "") {  
          $("label#heard_error").show();  
          $("input#heard").focus();  
          return false;  
        }     

        var applying = $("input#applying").val();  
        if (applying == "") {  
          $("label#applying_error").show();  
          $("input#applying").focus();  
          return false;  
        }    

        var strength = $("input#strength").val();  
        if (strength == "") {  
          $("label#strength_error").show();  
          $("input#strength").focus();  
          return false;  
        }   

        var weakness = $("input#weakness").val();  
        if (weakness == "") {  
          $("label#weakness_error").show();  
          $("input#weakness").focus();  
          return false;  
        }    

        var previousEx = $("input#previousEx").val();  
        if (previousEx == "") {  
          $("label#previousEx_error").show();  
          $("input#previousEx").focus();  
          return false;  
        }   



        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&mobile=' + mobile + '&college=' + college + '&university=' + university + '&level=' + level + '&first_preference=' + first_preference + '&second_preference=' + second_preference + '&third_preference=' + third_preference + '&heard=' + heard + '&applying=' + applying + '&strength=' + strength + '&weakness=' + weakness + '&previousEx=' + previousEx;

        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "php/database_sorting.php",
              data: dataString,
              success: function() {
                $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
                .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
                .hide()
                .fadeIn(1500, function() {
                  $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/done.png' />");
                });
              }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

[DEMO:](http://jsfiddle.net/Db2Uh/)

Comment: Can you provide what validation you want applied to the radio buttons? Also i should point out that doing a form submission via AJAX isn't entirely nice. It points out the potential paths that people can exploit, from this i'd see that I can directly access "php/database_sorting.php". Someone could parse in some SQL injection or random malformed data to try and exploit your scripts. It also doesn't work when JavaScript is disabled, you should look at getting the form validating server side and then enhance with JS instead of the other way around or purely skipping server side validation.

Comment: @Tom SQL injection can be attempted with Ajax or not, after all, you're sending a request to the server. I believe OP already knows, but yeah, you must do server-side validation if your site is public. For the non-JS enabled browsers, you either use Progressive enhancement (creating fallbacks for non-JS) or simply put a `<noscript>` tag in your page as the majority of JS-dependant pages do (for instance, in SO you can't post comments with JS disabled).

Comment: i wanna to make all the textfields and radiobuttons and text area are required :) ! without refreshing the page :) ! or at least without losing the data that entered by the user :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a radio buttons grouped by name, to check if one of them is selected:

```
//update the name to correspond to your radios group's name
if (!$('input[type="radio"][name="radiosGroup"]:checked').length) {
    alert('no radios selected!');
    //you can adapt the error message to your liking,
    //e.g. replacing the alert with $('#radio_error').show()
    return false;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/pBvZC/)

---

Another way to "skip" JS validation on radio buttons is to leave one of them pre-checked when you generate the page:

```
<input type="radio" name="radiosGroup" checked="checked" value="1" />
```

This way one of the radios will always be selected.

---

Using HTML5, you can use the `required` attribute on `input` elements (except button inputs) to skip JS validation for modern browsers. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/pBvZC/1/)

---

Finally, if all your `input`/`textarea`/`checkbox`/`radio`s are inside of a form, you can use jQuery's [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to generate a query string instead of building it manually. And if they aren't inside of a form, you can wrap them inside of one.

```
$('#myForm').serialize();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/pBvZC/2/)

---

And as already commented in the question, JS validation is just to provide a better UI (e.g. showing errors without refreshing the page), you need server-side validation if you're making your site public as JS can be easily bypassed.

---

One more side-note, assuming your `input`s are inside of a form, it's better to attach your validation to the form's [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) handler than on a button click, to ensure that your validation will be fired whenever the form is submitted independently of browser or user clicking in the submit button or pressing Enter in a text input element.